# How to return a Fractional expression in JAVA

Tags: java

I am making a fraction calculator in JAVA that keeps inputting a fraction and then an operator and then the next fraction and so on. I've successfully made this thing work for matrices and integers but can't make a function to input fraction so that I can call that function from the loop every time a new fraction has to be inputted.

This is how its working for now but I want the inputting fraction part to be another function so that the function could be used for various occasions .

```
System.out.println("Enter Numerator 1");
num1=Integer.parseInt(sc.readLine()); 

System.out.println("Enter Denominator 1");
den1=Integer.parseInt(sc.readLine()); 

System.out.println("Enter Numerator 2");
num2=Integer.parseInt(sc.readLine()); 

System.out.println("Enter Denominator 2");
den2=Integer.parseInt(sc.readLine());
```

Comment: Can you provide examples and some code to understand?

Comment: The problem is that you don't know how to read float number from input?

Comment: How do *you* want the user to enter a fraction? As `5/7`? `2 1/3`? Or what?

Comment: If you want a "helper" method for prompting the user for a fraction (Numerator + Denominator), then you need to be able to return two values from the helper method, so you need a `Fraction` class with those two values as *fields*, so the helper method can return a `Fraction`.

Comment: @Vadeg
Do you mean like->     float d= (float)Double.parseDouble(sc.readLine());
sc is BufferedReader

Comment: @AkhandYaduvanshi Yes

Comment: @Andreas Yeah,I want the user to input exactly the way you mentioned and could you help me with a snippet for the way method you just mentioned

Comment: @Vadeg So yup I know how to input a floating number, can this help somehow??

Comment: Just FYI, JAVA is not a thing. It's called Java. The letters don't stand for anything.

Comment: @Hack-R thanks, I kinda knew it but I always make this horrible mistake. So thanks for correcting me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example of a `Fraction` class that can prompt user for a new fraction.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Fraction {
    private final int nom;
    private final int den;
    public Fraction(int nom, int den) {
        if (den <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid denominator: " + den);
        this.nom = nom;
        this.den = den;
    }
    public int getNom() {
        return this.nom;
    }
    public int getDen() {
        return this.den;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (this.den == 1 ? String.valueOf(this.nom) : this.nom + "/" + this.den);
    }

    public static Fraction prompt(Scanner sc, String message) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?:(?:(\\d+)\\s+)?(\\d+)/)?(\\d+)\\s*");
        for (;;) {
            System.out.print(message + ": ");
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            if (m.matches()) {
                if (m.start(2) == -1)
                    return new Fraction(Integer.parseInt(m.group(3)), 1); // whole number
                int nom = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
                int den = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
                if (m.start(1) != -1)
                    nom += Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)) * den;
                return new Fraction(nom, den);
            }
            System.out.println("** Not a valid fraction. Please enter values like 2/3 or 4 3/7 or 13");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (;;) {
            Fraction fraction = Fraction.prompt(sc, "Enter value");
            if (fraction.getNom() == 0)
                break;
            System.out.println("You entered: " + fraction);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cool but how to perform operations on these , can you show with an example for multiplication

Comment: Check your math to figure out how you multiply two fractions, then write the code to create a new `Fraction` object with the `num` and `den` of the result of the multiplication.